# Ansible Blocks: "always" and "block" not working in main.yml

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use the "always" and "block" capabilities defined here - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html

I have a main.yml file that looks like this -

```
- block:
  - include: git_clone_and_combining.yml
    run_once: yes
    delegate_to: localhost

  - include: combined_repo_push.yml
    run_once: yes
    delegate_to: localhost

  - include: deploy_code.yml

  always:
  - include: resume_asg.yml
    delegate_to: localhost
```

It runs through the playbooks as expected, but the `always` block before "resume_asg.yml" script appears to be ignored, as it does not run on failure.  Is this use of blocks not supported on plays?

EDIT - Opened a ticket with Redhat about this, and they opened a Bug report here - https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/72941.  `Always` and `block` do not appear to work in main.yml when a `run_once` argument is specified.

Thanks.

Comment: The details are missing. Make it [mre].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from [*include*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_module.html#ansible-builtin-include-include-a-play-or-task-list)

> This module will still be supported for some time but we are looking at deprecating it in the near future.

A: I can reproduce the problem with *include*. To solve the problem, use [*include_tasks*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html#ansible-builtin-include-tasks-dynamically-include-a-task-list). For example

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - block:
        - include_tasks: test_fail.yml
          run_once: true
      always:
        - include_tasks: tasks-always.yml
```

```yaml
shell> cat test_fail.yml
- command: "{{ cmd|default('true') }}"
```

```yaml
shell> cat tasks-always.yml
- debug:
    msg: Always
```

give (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

TASK [command] ****
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Always
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e "cmd=false"

TASK [command] ****
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=true 
  cmd:
  - 'false'
  delta: '0:00:00.003130'
  end: '2020-12-11 21:29:26.481652'
  msg: non-zero return code
  rc: 1
  start: '2020-12-11 21:29:26.478522'
  stderr: ''
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: ''
  stdout_lines: <omitted>

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Always
```

---

The *always* section works as expected.

**Examples**

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - block:
        - command: "{{ cmd|default('true') }}"
      always:
        - debug:
            msg: Always
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ****

TASK [command] ****
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Always

  ...
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e "cmd=false"

PLAY [localhost] ****

TASK [command] ****
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=true 
  cmd:
  - 'false'
  delta: '0:00:00.004007'
  end: '2020-12-11 06:57:10.055177'
  msg: non-zero return code
  rc: 1
  start: '2020-12-11 06:57:10.051170'
  stderr: ''
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: ''
  stdout_lines: <omitted>

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Always

  ...
```

---

The included tasks give the same results

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - block:
        - command: "{{ cmd|default('true') }}"
      always:
        - include: tasks-always.yml

shell> cat tasks-always.yml
- debug:
    msg: Always
```

---

The role gives the same results

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - test-01

shell> cat roles/test-01/tasks/main.yml 
- block:
    - command: "{{ cmd|default('true') }}"
  always:
     - include: tasks-always.yml

shell> cat roles/test-01/tasks/tasks-always.yml 
- debug:
    msg: Always
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I actually opened a ticket with this to Red Hat, and they responded with -  "The task in the always section will not run if `run_once: yes` is specified in the failed task in the block section".  A bug report was opened here - "https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/72941"

Comment: [Works as expected with include_tasks instead of include.](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/72941#issuecomment-743405138).